# Google Apps Script For loop not repeating inside while loop

Tags: google-apps-script, nested-loops

I have long code wherein there is a while loop and inside that while loop there is a for loop and then an if statement. I want that for loop to run again and again until condition of the while loop is fulfilled. Although, that If statement keeps repeating under while loop I am not understanding why that For loop only runs once and never repeats. Please guide what is wrong in the code;

```
while(affDisc == 'NotClr'){
      //Finding affiliate discount row
      for(var i = 20; i <= odrEn && slsRprtSh.getRange('I' + i).getValue() > 0 && slsRprtSh.getRange('J' + i).getValue() == 0; i++){
        Logger.log(vndr + ' ' + i);
        Logger.log(minOdrRw);
        if(minOdr == 0){
          minOdr = slsRprtSh.getRange('I' + i).getValue();
          minOdrRw = i;
        }else if(slsRprtSh.getRange('I' + i).getValue() < minOdr){
          minOdr = slsRprtSh.getRange('I' + i).getValue();
          minOdrRw = i;
        }
      }
      //check if applying discount in minimum order fits here
      if(aggFloor - runinFloor > runinFloor + minOdr * .05 - aggFloor && slsRprtSh.getRange('J' + minOdrRw).getValue() == 0){
        Logger.log('runfloo  ' + runinFloor);
        //return false;
        slsRprtSh.getRange('J' + minOdrRw).setValue(minOdr * .05);
        slsRprtSh.getRange('J' + minOdrRw).setNote('5% discount for affiliate commission');
        slsRprtSh.getRange('L' + minOdrRw).setFormulaR1C1('=R[0]C[-3]-R[0]C[-2]');
        slsRprtSh.getRange('M' + minOdrRw).setFormulaR1C1('=R[0]C[-1]*0.15');
        slsRprtSh.getRange('N' + minOdrRw).setFormulaR1C1('=R[0]C[-1]+R[0]C[-2]');
        apldDisc = apldDisc + minOdr * .05;
        runinFloor = runinFloor + minOdr * .05;
      }else if(aggFloor - runinFloor < runinFloor + minOdr * .05 - aggFloor){
        affDisc = 'Clr';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe your condition is not fullfilled? Try to log `odrEn`, `slsRprtSh.getRange('I' + i).getValue()` and `slsRprtSh.getRange('J' + i).getValue()` within each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Thanks Zinganotschka, I didn't realize if my condition is not fulfilled then For loop will stop. My problem is that I want for loop to go through all iterations and skipping where condition is not fulfilled. What do I do for that?

Comment: For which condition exactly would you like to skip the iteration?